# Как брать из Excel документа точные, не преобразованные данные?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core, epplus

Беру данные вот так, возвращает True. Хочу брать точные данные то есть "ИСТИНА".

```
 namedWorksheet.Cells[$"E2"].Value.ToString();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формат данных "Общий"

Comment: это скорее всего вычисляемые ячейки, а текст генерится экселем, но не присутствует в ячейке. Но можно симулировать: `string cell = namedWorksheet.Cells[$"E2"].Value.ToString() == "True" ? "ИСТИНА" : "ЛОЖЬ";`. Можно еще так попробовать `string cell = namedWorksheet.Cells[$"E2"].Value is bool b && b ? "ИСТИНА" : "ЛОЖЬ";` Другими словами, вы перепутали, точные данные вы получаете, а преобразованные видите в таблице, то есть всё наоборот.

Comment: @aepot Но дней 5-6 назад я получал нормальные данные, файл тот-же, ничего не обновлял

Comment: Так помогло или нет? `файл тот-же, ничего не обновлял` - мой хрустальный шар говорит, что с этим что-то не так.

Comment: Возможно, не `.Value.ToString()`, а просто `.Text`? Не для диапазона! Для отдельной ячейки!